# How do you link an authenticated page with Devise in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I just set up Devise and things are working properly. However, for some reason, my page is not working together in authentication.

Here is my routes.rb file.

```
devise_for :users #, path_names: { sign_out: 'sign_out' }
devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'home#index'#, as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end

  get "/dashboard" => "home#index"
```

When I type in `localhost:3000`, it redirects me to the devise sign in page that exists on `localhost:3000/users/sign_in`.

When I type in `localhost:3000/dashboard`, it takes me to the sign in page as intended but when I enter my credentials, it keeps on bringing me back to the same sign in page over and over again.

Here is my application_controller.rb file.

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

My intention is to have `localhost:3000` redirect me to an authenticated version of `localhost:3000/dashboard` where I can see everything on that page. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Try something like this in your application controller `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  user_path(current_user)
end`

Comment: So I just added `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    dashboard_path
  end` for both application and home controllers (where the dashboard lives) but nothing happens. Any ideas? Pretty much, the sign in still keeps on going in a circular loop of signing in.

Comment: Okay, so I think I understand the problem but have no idea how to fix. My logout button doesn't redirect either. I'm adding def `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    dashboard_path
  end` and 

  `def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end` to my ApplicationController and nothing happens.

Comment: do you have any other page set as root? or dose your page default to devise sign_in? ive had this happen to me before and it was due to having two root 'mypage#something' set in routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to rewrite your code:

1. Remove `before_filter :authenticate_user!` as problem with unauthorized users already handled by routes.
2. Remove `devise_scope :user do ... end` block - there is a simpler solution (below).

Your **routes.rb** :

```
authenticated :user do
  root to: redirect('/dashboard'), as: :authenticated_root
end
root to: redirect('/users/sign_in')

get "dashboard" => "home#index"
```